# C# WinForms - SQL Server CE - SqlCeDataReader loses its data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-ce, sqlbulkcopy

I am trying to copy data from SQL Server database to SQL Server CE local database.

Here is my method :

```
private const string LOCAL_SDF_FILE = "LocalDB.sdf";
private const string LOCAL_CONN_STRING = "Data Source='|DataDirectory|LocalDB.sdf'; LCID=1033; Password=3C670F044A; Encrypt=TRUE;";
private const string SOURCE_CONN_STRING = "Data Source=SQL\\SERVER;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";

public static void CreateDB()
{
        if (File.Exists(LOCAL_SDF_FILE))
        {
            File.Delete(LOCAL_SDF_FILE);
        }

        SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(LOCAL_CONN_STRING);
        engine.CreateDatabase();
        engine.Dispose();

        SqlCeConnection localCnx = null;

        try
        {
            localCnx = new SqlCeConnection(LOCAL_CONN_STRING);
            localCnx.Open();

            SqlCeCommand localCmd = localCnx.CreateCommand();

            #region CREATE TABLE t_TypeConfig
            localCmd.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE t_TypeConfig(
                                        TypeConfig_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                                        TypeConfig_Name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
                                        TypeConfig_IsVisible bit NOT NULL,
                                        CONSTRAINT pk_TypeConfigID PRIMARY KEY (TypeConfig_ID)
                                    )";

            localCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            #endregion

            using (SqlConnection sourceCnx = new SqlConnection(SOURCE_CONN_STRING))
            {
                try
                {
                    sourceCnx.Open();

                    SqlCommand SourceCmd = sourceCnx.CreateCommand();
                    SourceCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t_TypeConfig";
                    SqlDataReader reader = SourceCmd.ExecuteReader();

                    using (SqlCeBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlCeBulkCopy(LOCAL_CONN_STRING))
                    {
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "t_TypeConfig";

                        try
                        {
                            // Write from the source (DB server) to the destination (local wibe)
                            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "An error occurred", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            reader.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "An error occurred", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                finally
                {
                    sourceCnx.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "An error occurred", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            localCnx.Close();
        }
    }
```

- Create SQL Server CE file and sample table (`t_TypeConfig`) -> ok.
- Get data into reader from SQL Server connection -> ok.

But when I want to fill, via `SqlCeBulkCopy`, my local database table with the reader I just filled previously, I see via Visual Studio watcher that `reader` does not contain the data anymore !

I don't know why. Still looking for a solution but I don't understand ? Maybe because the using ?

I also tried to convert the `SqlDataReader` into a `SqlCeDataReader` variable to give in `SqlCeBulkCopy.WriteToServer()` parameter but it cannot convert from one to other.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot,

Hellcat.

Comment: @marc_s SqlCeBulkCopy Works with DbDataReader just fine, so this should work. 
Did you let the process finish and check the database? And did you look in the right place: bin/debug folder !

Comment: Yea I took a look at bin/debug folder to find my .sdf file. I also tried to deal with a IDataReader instead of SqlDataReader.
I check the .sdf file content through the SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox for Visual Studio. But it is empty.
The first time, "reader" contains rows, the second time "reader" is used, it is empty, I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the solution is, thanks to guys in comments, to give as parameter to `SqlCeBulkCopy.WriteToServer()` a `DataTable` instead of a `SqlDataReader` or `IDataReader`.
It works for me right now.

Added this :

```
SqlDataReader reader = SourceCmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable SqlDatatable = new DataTable();
SqlDatatable.Load(reader);
```

Then :

```
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(SqlDatatable);
```

Thanks guys.